# Does a Warforged barbarian never get fatigued?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, eberron, barbarian, warforged

When a barbarian's rage ends, the character becomes *fatigued* for the rest of the scene, as per the rules in the PHB.

On the other hand, the warforged race (introduced in the Eberron campaign setting) is immune to *fatigue.*

**Does this mean that a warforged barbarian suffers no backlash after quitting rage?**

(I think it does, but I'd like to get this confirmed, preferably by some further official reference, if there is any.)

Comment: I don't have a book handy but are they immune to fatigue or do they just not require sleep? *Fatigue* doesn't necessarily mean *tired,* it could mean worn out or over-extended. A warforged's body could be *fatigued* after extended exertion, you just have to fluff it a little differently.

Comment: @Jason_c_o They are literally *immune* to fatigue. Eberron core, p.23.

Comment: Does the text say what whether a warforged can be exhausted (e.g. [*ray of exhaustion*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/rayOfExhaustion.htm), [*waves of exhaustion*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/wavesOfExhaustion.htm))?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yes, Warforged Barbarians suffer no ill-effects after raging.

From Races of Eberron, page 23:

> As a warforged, your Constitution bonus allows you to rage longer, your immunity to fatigue means you suffer no ill effect when your rage ends, ...

Answer (score 13):

**It does not get fatigued**

Well, technically what happens is the rage tries to apply the condition and then the barbarian ignores it, but "immunity" is pretty explicit - the warforged cannot suffer the effects of fatigue.

Comment: Thanks! I've upvoted your answer as well, but am accepting the other one because it cites an official source directly.